# How to put a specific monitor into standby mode?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, multiple-monitors

I have a multi monitor setup that has 4 monitors using two graphics cards and I need to switch only one of them into standby mode. I will explain the reason why for the curious down below...

This is how I am currently doing this: (It is putting them all into standby mode... I want only one).

```
const
  MON_ON      = -1;
  MON_OFF     =  2;

procedure TMain.btnMonOFFClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Screen.MonitorCount > 1 then
  begin
    SendMessage(Application.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MON_OFF);
  end;
end;
```

This as mentioned above of course works for all monitors but I want to know how I can assign this for a specific monitor [3]?

**The reason:** I keep getting the OSD appearing on monitor 3 randomly which is very annoying and I have to press the Menu button 4 times because it always appears upside down! so.. as a temporary solution for now I thought of putting the monitor into standby mode via a hotkey and then switching back on a few seconds later via a timer. Kind of like just blinking the monitor on and off which removes the OSD (On Screen Display) so I can continue working without getting mad. Yes, not fantastic or elegant but temporary until I can get a new monitor :)

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843908/how-to-put-monitor-on-standby-and-not-let-it-wake-up

Comment: @Graymatter - thank you for your pointer but I was hoping for something a little more language specific to help me. I cannot understand how I can use it for my needs.

Comment: I read this right as I turn off my computer's projector...

Comment: A projector is detached, I think, not put into standby. @Guillem - Why would you try something like that? A message is sent to a window.

Comment: @Guillem What happens is that the call to SendMessage fails because the first parameter is not an HWND

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and SertacAkyuz, thanks for the information. You always get to learn something new. :-)